# Understanding obscure PowerShell array syntax: Why does @(11..20+1) work while @(1+11..20) doesn't? How can I achieve the latter?

Tags: arrays, powershell, syntax

Consider the following:
(Note: I modified the output slightly for readability)

```powershell
~> @(11..20)
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

~> @(11..20+1)
11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 1

~> @(1+11..20)
InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
```

I've always found this array addition syntax to be confusing, and would much prefer something like `@(1,11..20)`.

At any rate, why does the 3rd operation not work identically to the 2nd?

Is it because `1` is not considered an array, even though it is being given as part of the array definition syntax?

```powershell
~> @(1,2+11..20)
1, 2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

If that's the case then why does `@(11..20+1)` work as expected?

I can work around this in a few ways...

```powershell
~> @(@(1)+11..20)
1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

~> @(,1+11..20)
1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20

~> @(11..20+1) | Sort
1, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

But those seem pretty ugly, inelegant, and the latter workaround doesn't account for instances where I don't actually want to sort the array.

The one that makes the most sense is `@(,1+11..20)`, though it's not particularly pleasing. Is there a more proper way to achieve the desired result in the desired order, without the additional syntax or piping?

None of the examples in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2) demonstrate this particular permutation.

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the `@( )`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`@(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), PowerShell's *array-subexpression operator* - which enumerates whatever `...` outputs and collects it in an `[object[]]` array - is only applied *after* `...` is evaluated, so we can leave it aside in this discussion.

Generally, in PowerShell it is the type of the *LHS* of an operation that determines what type-appropriate overload of the operation applies.

- In `11..20 + 1`, the LHS is an *array*, due to use of [`..`, the range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-), so the `+` operator performs *array concatenation*.
- In `1 + 11..20`, the LHS is a *scalar* - an `[int]` instance - so the `+` operator tries to perform *numerical addition*, which, however, fails, because adding an *array* to a number doesn't make sense and therefore isn't supported.

If you want to perform *array concatenation* with a *scalar* LHS, wrap that LHS in an *aux. array* using the unary form of `,`, the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-):

```
, 1 + 11..20
```

Alternatively, use one of the following:

- `@(1) + 11..20`
- `[array] 1 + 11..20`

If you don't know ahead of time whether the LHS actually *is* already an array, but you want it treat it as such if it isn't, the `[array]` cast is the most efficient solution:

```
[array] 1 + 11..20
```

Note that the cast only applies to `1`, based on PowerShell's [operator precedence rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence).

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot more sense understanding the role of `@()` and separating it from the array addition, rather than (inaccurately) thinking about the whole thing as being an array definition. Also re-internalizing the LHS rule is helpful. I've frequently struggled with code such as `foreach($x in $y)` when `$y` has the ability to end up as an "array" with a single item. I prefer untyped languages but these are the situations where it bites me.